# mongoose sort document by populated field with conditions

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database-design

i have two schema

`vehicle` schema :

```
const VehicleSchema = new Schema({
title: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
price: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
},
);
VehicleSchema.virtual('promotions', {
   ref: 'Promotion',
   localField: '_id',
   foreignField: 'vehicle',
   justOne: true
});
export default mongoose.model('Vehicle', VehicleSchema);
```

`Promotion` Schema :

```
const PromotionSchema = new Schema({
    start_at: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
    },
    end_at: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
    },
    vehicle: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Vehicle'
    },
    amount:{
        type:Number,
        required:true
    },
});
export default mongoose.model('Promotion', PromotionSchema);
```

every `vehicle` have multi `Promotion` and one of Promotions is active(`start_at` less then `Date.now` and `end_at` greater then `Date.now`)

1- i need to get all Vehicles with one Promotion(that now active) and sort its by `start_at`

2- is it possible to add virtual field with name `is_promotion` and set it to true if have active Promotion?

note: It is possible that some `Vehicle` do not have any `Promotion`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#specify-multiple-join-conditions-with-lookup).

$lookup promotions by vehicle id for a criteria and sort and limit to pick up the latest promotion.

[`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) to add the is_promotion field.

```
VehicleSchema.aggregate([
  {"$lookup":{
    "from":"Promotion",
    "let":{"_id":"$_id"},
    "pipeline":[
      {"$match":{
        "start_at":{"$lt":Date.now},
        "end_at":{"$gt":Date.now},
        "$expr":{"$eq":["$vehicle","$$_id"]}
      }},
      {"$sort":{"start_at":-1}},
      {"$limit":1}
    ],
    "as":"activepromotion"
  }},
  {"$addFields":{
    "is_promotion":{"$gt":[{"$size":"$activepromotion"},0]}
  }}
])
```

Answer (score -1):

### # Try it to get the start_at of our VehicleSchema, then use find() to search for this in the VehicleSchema field across all PromotionSchema.#

```
PromotionSchema
.findOne({ start_at: {
        type: Date
    } })
.populate('VehicleSchema') 
.exec(function (err, PromotionSchema) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);
  console.log('The total vehicles %s', PromotionSchema.VehicleSchema.vehicle);
.short(Date)
});
```

Comment: i need to get all vehicles not only vehicles that have Promotions